# Recursively adding subet

Tags: java, recursion, combinations

I have this case that works for the inputs:

```
{-5,0,5}, 2, 0   // which correctly evaluates to true
{-5,0,5}, 3, 4   // which correctly evaluates to false
{-5,0,5}, 3, 0   // which correctly evaluates to true
```

but with the input:

```
{6,5,6}, 2, 12  // says false when true
```

it doesn't get give the correct boolean value...
Can someone help debug the problem?

```
public static boolean subset(int[] array, int n, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int[] list = new int[array.length - 1];

        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
            list[j] = array[j+1];
        }
        subset(list, n, target);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    if (sum == target) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what the method is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're trying to calculate, but I suspect your problem lies in the recursive call of subset(list,n,target). You aren't changing an object and you are ignoring the return value.
In addition: You're not using the variable "n" at all.

Answer (score 0):

You do nothing with return value of your recursion.

This line :

```
subset(list, n, target);
```

Should be changed to :

```
if (subset(list, n, target)){
    return true;
}
```

Also, you do not do anything with your `n` variable

---

I like you are trying hard man, so I make it a little easier for you :).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int n = 3;
    int sum = 10;
    System.out.println(subset(array, n, sum));
}

public static boolean subset(int[] array, int n, int sum) {
    //If I have enough numbers in my subarray, I can check, if it is equal to my sum
    if (array.length == n) {
        //If it is equal, I found subarray I was looking for
        if (addArrayInt(array) == sum) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Trying all possibilites and doing recursion
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        //if some recursion returned true, I found it, so I can also return true
        int[] subarray = new int[array.length - 1];
        int k = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < subarray.length; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                k++;
            }
            subarray[j] = array[j + k];
        }
        if (subset(subarray, n, sum)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //If I didnt find anything, I have to return false
    return false;
}

public static int addArrayInt(int[] array) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        res += array[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

However, you dont understand basics of recursion, you are close, but I think you are missing the main idea :). I would recommend you to try compute Factorial recursively and then Fibonacci, it can help and there are tutorials all over the internet.

Comment: Is there a way to so this while keeping the original signature on the method?

Comment: @user3362954 - Same parameters, right? Well it was possible, look to edited code

Comment: I respect you for helping me so much!